# How do you extend Django's sitemap module to create more complex sitemaps?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I have a supplier that wants a sitemap that contains much more meta data than what you would see in a normal search engine sitemap. As a result I would like find a tidy way of extending django's sitemap module. Has anyone done this? Or could you provide this django Noob with the code to do it?

Mike

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you sure it's not possible with the Sitemap class? See also: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this you would need to extend `django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.get_urls` to add the additional meta information to the `url_info` dictionary. The current `get_urls` is given below from [django.contrib.sitemaps](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py):

```
def get_urls(self, page=1, site=None):
    if site is None:
        if Site._meta.installed:
            try:
                site = Site.objects.get_current()
            except Site.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        if site is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("In order to use Sitemaps you must either use the sites framework or pass in a Site or RequestSite object in your view code.")

    urls = []
    for item in self.paginator.page(page).object_list:
        loc = "http://%s%s" % (site.domain, self.__get('location', item))
        priority = self.__get('priority', item, None)
        url_info = {
            'location':   loc,
            'lastmod':    self.__get('lastmod', item, None),
            'changefreq': self.__get('changefreq', item, None),
            'priority':   str(priority is not None and priority or '')
        }
        urls.append(url_info)
    return urls
```

After that you would need to change [`django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/sitemap.xml`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/sitemap.xml) to include your extra information in the sitemap. Unrelated to Django if you are adding extra meta information you should read up on the sitemaps.org protocol section regarding [extending the protocol](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php#extending).